# Replace part of a video (without replacing the audio) in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, batch-file, cmd.exe, video-editing

I have a video file that is divided into three different sections. I want to replace the middle part of this video with another clip. However, I still want to keep the audio of the original video. Can I do that in ffmpeg?

Here are my requirements:

1. Original Video is 60 seconds long.
2. The part I want to replace is from 25 to 45 seconds.
3. I want to keep the original audio from 25 to 45 seconds and just replace the visual part with some other clip.
4. The generated video will also be 60 seconds long. However, it will have the new video from 25 to 45 seconds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want to do is three separate steps:

1. split the original input into three clips (0-25, 25-45, 45-60)
2. modify the middle clip to use orginal audio and custom video (see below)
3. [concatenate all three clips](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

In order to get the middle clip with original audio and new video you could simply use the [-map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) option:

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -i newvideo.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 newmiddle.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks @rauberdaniel. :) Unfortunately, joining the files together gives me an error about `Non-monotonous DTS in output stream`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple method is to use the [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) filter to add a delay to `new.mp4`, and then the [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filter with the [`enable`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) option to place `new.mp4` over `original.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -i new.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+25/TB[fg];[0][fg]overlay=enable='between(t,25,45)'[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:a copy output.mp4
```

- This assumes `new.mp4` has the same width x height as `original.mp4`. If not, then add the scale, scale2ref, pad, and/or crop filter.
- Remove setpts if you want `new.mp4` to play at its own timestamp of 25 seconds instead of at timestamp 0 when overlaid.